# Add new data on top of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have a problem with my recyclerview. Whenever I insert new data, it wont be on top of the recycler view.

This is my code to insert new data

```
 dbRefForm = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("LIST OF FORM");
 dbRefForm.child(ic_number).setValue(formDataTwo);
```

My Firebase looks like this. [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IyCM.png)

I also set my recyclerview

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ViewApplicationActivity.this);
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

what did i missed?

Comment: Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168245/recyclerview-reverse-order/46168428)

Comment: yes, i have tried it. but because im using child "ic_number". the recyclerview position in ascending order according to the value number in "ic_number" not the latest data that i inserted