# How to reverse recyclerView items with CoordinatorLayout as root layout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

How to reverse recyclerView items with CoordinatorLayout as root layout?

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_main_students"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
         />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and `app:reverseLayout="true"` not working for recyclerview.

Note: I want reverse recyclerView not reverese collection

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168245/recyclerview-reverse-order

Answer (score 1):

solution 1- reverse list of input data

```
fun <T> reverseList(list: List<T>): ArrayList<T> {
return (list.indices)
    .map { i: Int -> list[list.size - 1 - i] }
    .toCollection(ArrayList())
}
```

follow- https://www.techiedelight.com/reverse-copy-list-kotlin/

Solution 2

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to reverse the list. You can do this:

```
Collections.reverse(mList); // enter your list here
```

In your xml add this ->

```
app:stackFromEnd="true"
```

**NOTE:** if you are doing some operations with the adapter position and the list in the adapter, then first reverse and then pass it to the adapter. Or else you gotta face and issue

Comment: it's worked but I want reverse recyclerView not reverese collection

Comment: Not working any changes on xml code

Comment: Then try `app:reverseLayout="true"`

Comment: this methods not working for androidx.recyclerview

Comment: I don't know why it is not working for you. it works fine for me. See the screenshot -> [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DBjP.png)

Comment: Are your root layout is coordinatorLayout?

Comment: yes. it is coordinator layout