# reverse layout and stack from end throwing error

Tags: android, kotlin

```
 private fun initRecyclerView(){
       studentRecyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)

        layoutManager.reverseLayout=true
        layoutManager.stackFromEnd=true

        adapter = StudentRecyclerViewAdapter{
            selectedItem:Student -> listitemclicked(selectedItem)
        }
        studentRecyclerView.adapter=adapter
        displayStudentList()
    }
```

I want to reverse the recycler view, but whenever I use `layoutManager.reverseLayout` and `layoutManager.stackFromEnd` these lines throw an error.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Could you start by editing your post to include what error you have?

Comment: Also, this is just guesswork, but shouldn't `layoutManager` be `studentRecyclerView.layoutManager`?

Comment: this reverselayout and stackFromEnd could be used with the variable name but i do not know what is variable name in this beacuse i do not declare any variable of layout manager above

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168245/recyclerview-reverse-order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setReverseLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#setReverseLayout(boolean)) and [`setStackFromEnd`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager#setStackFromEnd(boolean)) are both functions on the `LinearLayoutManager` class, *not* the base `LayoutManager` one. So you have to make sure the variable you're referencing has a `LinearLayoutManager` type (or cast it):

```
// implicitly setting the type to the class you're constructing
val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

// or you can just specify it explicitly
val layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

// now you can configure that object, and set it on the RecyclerView
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true)
studentRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

---

`studentRecyclerView.layoutManager`'s type is just the base `LayoutManager` (so you can provide different implementations of a layout manager), so if you *read* that property you'll just get a `LayoutManager`. If you wanted to treat it as a `LinearLayoutManager` specifically (and access the functions and properties on that type), you'd have to cast it:

```
studentRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
...
(studentRecyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).setReverseLayout(true)
```

This is messy though, and it's usually better to just hold your own reference with the correct type - no need to complicate things, especially during a simple setup block!

---

And because it's Kotlin, `set*` functions can be written as a property (e.g. `layoutManager.reverseLayout = true`) and the IDE will offer to change the function version to the property version, if appropriate. Same thing though, just a different way of writing it.